# How to build eclipse project files for android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

When I download an android project - open source or samples etc from the web. They don't come with following files which are required to build the projectin eclipse.

```
.project
project.properties
.classpath
```

As a result I copy these files manually from some existing project, copy them to the root of this given project, manually edit them to change project name + target in project.properties

I have to repeat these every time I download a new project for example any open source android project.

Then I go to eclipse file -> Import existing project into workspace to build the project and use it.

My Question is : Is there a proper way to import an android project in eclipse so that these above files are automatically created ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing the following way: File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android Code Into Workspace.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes I had worked that out, thanks for the answer, I accept it